# Shell Exec Jar Php

Tags: php, ubuntu, jar, exec, shell-exec

I'm trying to execute a jar in PhP with this line

shell_exec("java -jar OCR.jar 2.jpeg /opt/lampp/htdocs/output/");

In the terminal this jar works well but in php not.

How fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

try calling

```
which java
```

in ubuntu console, this will probably give you

```
/usr/bin/java
```

so use the full path

also I suggest calling exec($command, $output) and print the output array to get more info. to redirect stderr stream to stdout end your command with 2>&1 , e.g.

```
 /usr/bin/java -jar OCR.jar 2.jpeg /opt/lampp/htdocs/output/ 2>&1
```

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 2.jpeg (Permission denied) at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method) at java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:241) at javax.imageio.stream.FileImageOutputStream.(FileImageOutputStream.java:69) at com.sun.imageio.spi.FileImageOutputStreamSpi.createOutputStreamInstance(FileImageOutputStreamSpi.java:55) at javax.imageio.ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(ImageIO.java:419) at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1530)

Comment: probably you'll need a full path to 2.jpeg too, also check read permissions

Comment: After a change permissions from 2.jpeg